# Replacing NULL with empty string in jQuery each()?

Tags: jquery, replace, null

The parameter *fights* below is the result from an Ajax call. Some of the data has `NULL` values. What's a simple way of replacing those values with an empty string?

```
    function createFightsTable(fights) {

        $.each(fights, function() {

            $("#professional_fights_table tbody").append("<tr><td class='text-center'>" + this.result  + "</td><td>" + this.record  + "</td><td>" + this.opponent  + "</td><td>" + this.method  + "</td><td>" + this.date  + "</td><td class='text-center'>" + this.round  + "</td><td>" + this.time  + "</td></tr>"); 
        });
    }
```

Comment: It depends, is it `"NULL"` (a string, perhaps coming from a database result set where `NULL` was converted to a string), or `null` (the actual `null` value in JavaScript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether it's `"NULL"` (a string, perhaps coming from a database result set where `NULL` was converted to a string) or `null` (the actual `null` value in JavaScript).

If it's `"NULL"`, you probably want a utility function:

```
function blankForNull(s) {
    return s.toUpperCase() === "NULL" ? "" : s;
}
```

Then:

```
$("#professional_fights_table tbody").append("<tr><td class='text-center'>" + blankForNull(this.result)  + // ...
```

If it's `null`, you can use the curiously-powerful `||` operator or the newer (ES2020) "null coalescing" operator `??`:

```
$("#professional_fights_table tbody").append("<tr><td class='text-center'>" + (this.result || "")  + // ...
```

or

```
$("#professional_fights_table tbody").append("<tr><td class='text-center'>" + (this.result ?? "")  + // ...
```

(You do need the `()` around it in that concatenation expression.)

Comment: It's the actual `null` value in JavaScript. `(this.result || "")` worked great. Thanks! In another place of the code I append the data like this: `$(".list-group").append('<a href="#">' +  this.name + ", " + this.age + ", " + this.gender + '</a>');`. Do you know how to only put a comma after a value if it's not an empty string?

Comment: @RawlandHustle - You could do ...`+ [this.name, this.age, this.gender].filter(Boolean).join(", ") +`... The `filter` removes any falsy entries (like empty strings). (`.filter(Boolean)` could be `.filter(e => e)` if you like.) Or give yourself a utility function to do it without the temp array.